# SQL dialect in H2

Tags: java, db2, h2

I have a file which contains SQL "insert" statements. I open this file, read it and then try to insert it in the database(table is already there). Statements are of the form:

```
Insert into table1 Select 1,....
Insert into table1 Select 2,....
Insert into table1 Select 3,....
;
```

';' comes after a bunch of lines.

These statements are workin fine in actual DB2 server, but not working in H2. I have also tried MODE=DB2, but still not working.

To make it work, I inserted ';' after every line. So, statements became:

```
Insert into table1 select 1,....;
Insert into table1 Select 2,....;
Insert into table1 Select 3,....;
;
```

When I try to insert these statements in H2 console, it works fine. But in java program, it gives error because of two consecutive ';'.

Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: You need to execute the statements individually. The H2 Console also executes each statement individually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely confident I understand what comes after your "select", as I'm used to either "values (...)" or a select statement referencing another table, which usually can be crafted into a single statement using something like ROW_NUMBER() for the values shown.

If you have a high volume of inserts, try using PreparedStatement's addBatch() method.  It's fast, very secure when implemented properly, and has the least impact on your database resources (like its statement cache).

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?,?)");
pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
pstmt.setString(2, "example");
pstmt.addBatch();
pstmt.setInt(1, 2);
pstmt.setString(2, "I should really loop through an array here...");
pstmt.addBatch();
int[] updCnt = pstmt.executeBatch();
con.commit();
```